# Login kickout every time in Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, login

We have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in our production servers. Our dedicated server disk was filled, due to that issue, one of the production servers stopped.

While troubleshooting I found that disk was full (100% used). I have moved the particular VM to another host now. While starting my VM worked fine and reached the login screen. While login using our username and password it keeps kicking me out. This is not a desktop environment.

I have done some of the steps.

I can't `ping` the machine now, I can't `ssh` the machine either.

1. Boot from CD and tried to check the file system in recovery mode.

   ```
   fsck.ext4 -y /dev/mapper/production_srv_root
   ```

This did not fix the issue.

2. Tried to boot the System into Recovery mode

Then tried to access the root shell. I can't reach the shell before that it's getting some kernel error. The error was not repeating so I can't provide that one here.

This is production machine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just a clarification, it was the disk that held the VM that was full? Not the VM's own disk?

Comment: Yes your right, host disk was full not the VM disk